# It is possible to pass additional objects aside the response.data in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, response

I would like my browser could returns:

> res.data ;
>
> res.additionalObject ;
>
> res.otherAdittionalObject ;
>
> etc.

The problem is that the res.data is an array of object, then mapping in it would be more difficult if I add other objects directly in this array of objects.

I'd prefer to create others objects aside the res.data object, if it is possible.

I have tried `res.write(additionalObject); res.end() ;` but it fails.

Any hint would be great,

thanks.

Comment: If the additional information is short enough, you could use HTTP headers

Comment: yes is two string of index numbers , okay I see thanks

Comment: res.json(objects) then you use js handle the render on the frontend ?